# Error that the adjacency matrix is not symmetric

Tags: r, graph, igraph, statnet

My dataset is as follows, I want to create a network but the error is that my adjacency matrix is not symmetric, I am new to R, I don't know how to convert my data to symmetric adjacency matrix, can any one help me please?

```
df2:
17  "RobertKennedyJr" "RobertKennedyJr "             
18  "Real_Sheezzii"   "Real_Sheezzii "               
19  "Kellie_Martin"   "Kellie_Martin "               
20  "ThatsOurWaldo"   "ThatsOurWaldo "               
21  "SCN_Nkosi"       "SCN_Nkosi "                   
22  "azsweetheart013" "azsweetheart013 "             
23  "KYourrights"     "KYourrights KathyConWom"      
24  "GowTolson"       " KathyConWom"                 
25  "Peterpu52451065" " KathyConWom"                 
26  "Jifchoppa"       " KathyConWom"                 
27  "ClaraLpz3"       " KathyConWom"                 
28  "Anna5705"        " KathyConWom"                 
29  "Brizzle254"      " KathyConWom"                 
30  "JackSpa02102454" " KathyConWom"
```

The code that I tried

```
library("igraph")
library("network")
library("statnet")
relationsp <- as.matrix(df2)
relationsp



net <- as.network(x = mat, # the network object
                  directed = TRUE, # specify whether the network is directed
                  loops = FALSE, # do we allow self ties (should not allow them)
                  matrix.type = "adjacency" # the type of input
)
```

Comment: You used `matrix.type = "adjacency"` but your matrix looks like it is actually an edgelist.  Try `matrix.type = "edgelist"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are applying `igraph` package, you should use `graph_from_data_frame` to create the graph object `net`, which is followed by `get.adjacency` to obtain the adjacency matrix, e.g.,

```
> net <- graph_from_data_frame(dat)

> get.adjacency(net, sparse = FALSE)
                RobertKennedyJr Real_Sheezzii Kellie_Martin GowTolson ClaraLpz3
RobertKennedyJr               1             0             0         0         0
Real_Sheezzii                 0             1             0         0         0
Kellie_Martin                 0             0             1         0         0
GowTolson                     0             0             0         0         0
ClaraLpz3                     0             0             0         0         0
KathyConWom                   0             0             0         0         0
                KathyConWom
RobertKennedyJr           0
Real_Sheezzii             0
Kellie_Martin             0
GowTolson                 1
ClaraLpz3                 1
KathyConWom               0
```